# Insert link based on number in string

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I'm trying add links to emails. A typical email would look something like this:

> Hello, I noticed that Order 12345 seems to be incomplete. Specifically, how many widgets were you looking to purchase? Please update Order 12345 with the correct widget quantity. Thank you.

Anywhere "Order 12345" appears, I want to insert a link to http://something.com/order.html?o=12345.
The email format may change, and the order number may change. I want any instance of "Order" followed by any number to be linked to the appropriate order page on the website.

RegEx seems like the obvious answer. I enabled the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library in my project, and wrote the following code based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx:

```vb
Sub Add_Order_Links()
    Dim miMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim rgx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    
    strPattern = "Order \d+"
    strReplace = "<a href='http://something.com/order.html\?o=$1'>Order $1</a>"
    
    Set miMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If miMessage Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    strBody = miMessage.HTMLBody
    rgx.Pattern = strPattern
    rgx.Global = True
    rgx.IgnoreCase = True
    miMessage.HTMLBody = rgx.Replace(strBody, strReplace)
End Sub
```

The script finds the matching "Order 12345" instances and inserts the links, but instead of "Order 12345" I get "Order $1" and ?o=$1 in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Without a [capturing group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kstkz771%28v=vs.84%29.aspx#Anchor_1) in your regular expression there's nothing to [back-reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhdcs5c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to.

Change this:

```
strPattern = "Order \d+"
```

into this:

```
strPattern = "Order (\d+)"
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Interesting. I think I'd go with `(Order)\s(\d+)` to make the whitespace explicit... and because I like groups. Nice answer, taught me something =)